# Counting the number of configurations without permutations

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{A} = \left\{1,2,...,M\right\}$, and let $N>M$ be some natural number.

A configuration is a string of $N$ numbers where each of the $N$ numbers takes values in $\mathcal{A}$. For example, if $\mathcal{A} = \left\{1,2\right\}$, and $N=3$, then possible configurations are
\begin{align}
1,1,1\\
1,1,2
\end{align}
and so on. I want to count the number of possible configurations **excluding** permutations. So, for the previous example, this number is equal to $4$, where the possible configurations are (of course, we can choose other permuted configurations)
\begin{align}
1,1,1\\
1,1,2\\
1,2,2\\
2,2,2
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially asking for non-decreasing sequences of $N$ elements of $\mathcal{A}$, i.e., numbers in the range $1 \ldots M$.
Say a configuration is $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_N$, take:
\begin{align}
x_0 &= a_1 - 1 \\
x_1 &= a_2 - a_1 \\
    &\vdots \\
x_N &= a_N - a_{N - 1} \\
X_{N + 1} &= M - a_n
\end{align}
Note that this way $x_0 + \ldots + x_{N + 1} = M - 1$.
Your restrictions mean that each $x_k \ge 0$, and that (by the [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) argument) has just:
$$
\binom{(N + 2) + (M - 1) - 1}{M - 1} = \binom{M + N}{M - 1}
$$
solutions.

Answer (score 2):

consider $A=\{1,2,...m\}$ and $N$. Then suppose a string consists of $X_{i}$ copies of $1\leq i \leq m$. Then the number of strings is in one to one correspondence with solutions to $$X_{1}+X_{2}+...+X_{m}=N.$$

Comment: And finding the number of solutions of that equation is a question that has been asked and answered on this site many times.